# SQL-Server: Query to return codes only with numbers beginning with letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that returns values in a table that begin with the letters A-Z as their first character and subsequently are followed by only numbers.

Example:

`[table].Code`:

```
0056
A0089
X0023
J0F5
09AG
A91234671
A945353B
```

Query would return the following results:

```
A0089
X0023
A91234671
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[A-Z]` to check the first character and `ISNUMERIC` to check all characters except from the first one for being a number:

```
SELECT Code 
FROM mytable 
WHERE LEFT(Code,1) LIKE '[A-Z]' AND ISNUMERIC(RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code)-1)) = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ede2b/1)

**EDIT:**

As stated in comment by @Dan `ISNUMERIC` might fail to give you the result you want, in case `Code` field contains characters like `+`, `-`. You can try this instead:

```
SELECT Code 
FROM mytable 
WHERE LEFT(Code,1) LIKE '[A-Z]' AND 
      RIGHT(Code, LEN(Code)-1) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc61c/4)

Comment: Note that ISNUMERIC behaves a little funny with some characters. For example, `ISNUMERIC('$')`, `ISNUMERIC('.')` and `ISNUMERIC('-')` might return something different from what you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` with pattern matching. The `[A-Z]` will match any value between `A` `Z` for first character of code. And if you want to match the small caps also then you can include `[a-z]` in the query

```
  SELECT
     Code 
  FROM 
     tablename 
  WHERE 
      LEFT(Code,1) LIKE '[A-Z]%'
```

[Here is more info on LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use pattern matching

```
select * from table where left(code,1) like '[a-Z][a-Z]%'
```